# How to fix Ctrl Click in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-server

I found, that `Ctrl-Click` (for example, on class usage) doesn't work on one of my installations of Idea. Simultaneously:

- Context menu action like `Go To -> Implementation(s)` works
- Control click in `PyCharm` works

Machine is remote desktop Windows Server 2016. Idea is 2021.2.

What can be done to fix?

Comment: Do you use CMake build system?

Comment: I am creating Hello World (Java) project from example from scratch, no CMake, no any other 3rd party build system.

Comment: Try to temporarly disable all third-party plugins - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html. If the problem remains please contact IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new .

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue due to Rider importing settings from Visual Studio on the first run. Resolved it by changing the Keymap (Rider->Preferences->Keymap->Keymap drop down) back to the default one (IntelliJ).

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was really an old SonarLint plugin. Check in Settings / Plugins. After the update the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and going to File -> Reapair IDE... fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that the Ctrl + Click was opening the wrong file - from the virtual environment, rather than the source file.

This was because I was using a Poetry environment. So my fix was to right click on the `src/` folder and to both mark it as the sources root, as well as the resources root.